# problem with useEffect and useState in fake chat app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My program is fake chat App, using useEffect, useState, it will emit a comment per 2 second and display all comments on each lesson. In the first render, it run correctly(emit a comment per 2 second), but in each re-render, it emit 2 comments per 2 second.

I try to console.log(newLessonComments[lessonId - 1].comments.length) after push a comment. And it only push 1 comment to the array.

What is the problem?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function Content() {
    let lessons = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Bài học 1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Bài học 2'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Bài học 3'
        }
    ];
    const [lessonId, setLessonId] = useState(1);
    const [lessonComment, setLessonComment] = useState(() => {
        return lessons.map(lesson => {
            return {
                id: lesson.id,
                comments: []
            }
        });
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleComment = ({ detail }) => {
            setLessonComment(prev => {
                const newLessonComments = prev.slice(0);
                newLessonComments[lessonId - 1].comments.push(detail);
                return newLessonComments;
            });
        }
        window.addEventListener(`lesson${lessonId}`, handleComment);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener(`lesson${lessonId}`, handleComment);
        }
    }, [lessonId])
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {lessons.map(lesson => {
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={lesson.id}
                            style={{
                                color: lessonId == lesson.id ? 'red' : '#333',
                                cursor: 'pointer'
                            }}
                            onClick={() => { setLessonId(lesson.id) }}
                        >
                            {lesson.title}
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            <div className="comments">
                <ul>
                    {lessonComment[lessonId - 1].comments.map((comment, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li
                                key={index}
                            >
                                {comment}
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Content;
```

```
function emitComments(id) {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('emit comments')
        window.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent(`lesson${id}`, {
                detail: `Nội dung comments của lesson ${id}`
            })
        ) 
    }, 2000)
}

emitComments(1);
emitComments(2);
emitComments(3);
```

Comment: Where does `emitComments` get called? If it gets called when you mount a component then you'll end up adding a new setInterval each time you render

Comment: Try to call `emitComments` in `useEffect`

Comment: i call it in useEffect. but it still the same